# Modifiying a file in editor automatically

Tags: linux, text-editors, editing

I'm trying to change a ppt to beamer. Here's the strategy I'm following:

1. Copy all bullets from the ppt (open office)
2. Paste it in an editor (gedit?)
3. Hit `save`. (Here, it should call the sed script sed -i 's/^/\item /' *filename* )
4. Editor should see the changes and reload so that I can copy/paste to my beamer source.

Can someone point me to an editor where I can extend the on-save functionality to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ allows scripts and macros, it is also opensource, so you could easily change the "Save" command to run the script, with a little bit of elbow grease.

Comment: I have the linux tag there and I don't think Notepad++ is available on Linux.

Comment: You can run Notepad++ in WINE

Comment: No offense but I never agree with solutions that ask me to use WINE. If I wanted to use Windows, I would've stayed on windows.

Comment: No offence taken, I offered you a solution you're capable of using. Whether you decide to use it or not is entirely up to you. You could download a simple open source text editor available for Linux and do the exact same thing I suggested you do with Notepad++.